# How to properly write a datatable.Compute(string) when it gives a undetailed error?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm creating a data table with doubles, like this

[image]

And i'm using another double that depends on user input to fix itself the 2 immediate above, and 2 immediate below rows.

```
double razao = Variables.dadocobplanaW / Variables.alturaW;

 double min = Convert.ToDouble(DataAccess.Instance.tabelaplanaplatibandaW.Compute("MIN(Variavel)", "Variavel > " + razao.ToString()));
 double max = Convert.ToDouble(DataAccess.Instance.tabelaplanaplatibandaW.Compute("MAX(Variavel)", "Variavel < " + razao.ToString()));


 DataRow[] rows = DataAccess.Instance.tabelaplanaamansardadaW.Select("Variavel = " + min.ToString() + " OR " + "Variavel = " + max.ToString());
```

I already re-verified the tables, and their names, and everything is right, the code runs, but when i get a value into `razao` the program will crash when trying to find `min` and `max`

Is it because I have 2 lines with the same `Variavel` on every case?

Any hint?

Edit: here's the error message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be caused by incorrect format of `razao.ToString(), min.ToString(), max.ToString()`; check the delimiter in those strings. It should be `'.'`, I suppose.
If you have comma `','`; try this `razao.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: I have a comma because it's a string. I tought it could be that too, because a double in the code uses ".", and a string uses ","  Maybe i didn't got it right, but used this `double min = Convert.ToDouble(DataAccess.Instance.tabelaplanaplatibanda1W.Compute("MIN(Variavel)", "Variavel >= " + razao.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));` and it gave "culture info" does not exist in this context.

Comment: add `using System.Globalization;` in code file or use full type name `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: It worked, i presume it gets the string while keeping the dot "." instead of converting the double to a string with a comma ",". am I right? Does this only affect the parameters that have `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` the rest stays intact?

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive answer? I'm pretty sure this is useful for a lot of people, anyways I'm upvoting it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is about parsing expressions used by `compute()` method.

You can verify it by using below code, and seems you don't need doubles!

```
String min = DataAccess.Instance.tabelaplanaplatibandaW.Compute("MIN(Variavel)", String.Format(@"Variavel > {0}", razao.ToString())).ToString();
```

After that you need to find the behind code of `compute()` method.
That method uses an expression parser that probably read data from your table and parse it to a node of `System.Data`. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The problem is in filter part and when `Variavel` and `razao` are parsing to System.Double.

In Above link says :

> For example, if the number in the literal is 2147483650, DataSet will
>   first attempt to parse the number as an Int32. This will not succeed
>   because the number is too large. In this case DataSet will parse the
>   number as an Int64, which will succeed. If the literal was a number
>   larger than the maximum value of an Int64, DataSet will parse the
>   literal using Double. 
>   Real literals using scientific notation, such as 4.42372E-30, are
>   parsed using System.Double.

Anyway you can change your way, and take the Min and Max from DB.
That I usually use it.